# How to prevent redundant api calls in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Following is my code:

```
created() {
this.$validator.extend('available', {
  getMessage: () => 'This user already exists.',
  validate: async (value, args) => {
    const result = await this.emailValidation(value, args);

    return result;
  },
});
},

methods(){ 
async emailValidation(value, args) {
  if (value !== null && args.indexOf(value) === -1) {
    const request = {
      email: value,
      id: store.state.id,
    };
    const response = await this.verifyEmail(request);

    return response && response.data ? response.data.available : false;
  }

  return true;
}, 
},
```

And following is the text field:

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="email"
  v-validate="
    dialogLabel !== 'Add User' ? 'required|email|available:' + email : 'required|email|available'
  "
  data-test-id="email"
  :error-messages="errors.first('email')"
  data-vv-name="email"
  label="Email"
  placeholder="Email"
  required
  clearable
  @change="changeEmail()"
/>
```

When I add full email id, at that time also it gives API call i.e. before loosing the focus and also on blur it gives API call again to validate email id.

I want to make only one call. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you try using the [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) event instead?

Comment: What validator library are you using? Most of them support a debounce feature.

Comment: VeeValidate library

Comment: Debounce might not be what you're looking for - you wouldn't want to validate the same email more than once, even if it would happen after a certain amount of time. Why not store the last email that was checked during an API call whenever you call your validation method, and only make that API call again if the email is different than the one you stored?